# Himmel, Arsch und Zwirn?

Tags: etymology

Wo kommt der Fluch/Ausruf "**Himmel, Arsch und Zwirn!**" her? Gibt es Verbindungen zu "**Verflixt und zugenäht!**"?

Wie kam es, dass *"Zwirn"* mancherorts durch *"Wolkenbruch"* ersetzt wurde? Oder lief die Ersetzung in umgekehrter Richtung?

Comment: Grimm's Wörterbuch hat natürlich wieder was zu sagen: Zum *Zwirn* wird erwähnt, dass er als Euphemismus für das männliche Sperma verwendet wurde, z.B. "er hat seinen Zwirn andernorts vernäht" als Euphemismus für "fremdgehen".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aus dem Brockhauskalender *[Was so nicht im Lexikon steht 2011](http://www.amazon.de/Brockhaus-nicht-Lexikon-steht-2011/dp/3840000106)* (Eintrag vom 3. Januar):

> #### Wie kommt der Zwirn in den Fluch?
>
> Für zweierlei waren in alten Zeiten die Deutschen in ganz Europa berüchtigt: fürs Saufen und fürs Fluchen. Aber was die anderen von uns hielten, ging uns glatt am ... vorbei. Dieses Element des besagten Fluchs wäre also geklärt. Und dass, trotz Sündhaftigkeit, auch etws Religiöses wie der Himmel in einen Fluch gehört, versteht sich von selbst. Nur, verflixt und zugenäht!, was ist mit dem Zwirn?
>   Ein Zwirn entsteht durch das Zusammendrehen von mindestens zwei Fäden, was ihn gegenüber dem Einzelfaden natürlich haltbarer macht. **Der Zwirn verleiht** also **dem zuvor Gesagten** einen ordentlichen **Nachdruck**.
>   Aber er steht hier nicht allein deswegen. Das innige Aneinanderschmiegen und Ineinanderverdrehen von zwei Einzelfäden birgt auch ein metaphorisches Potenzial. **Zwirnen wurde früher als Synonym für körperliche Verwicklungen**, kurz: fürs Vögeln, **verwendet**. Damit wären mit den drei Wörtern des Fluchs wesentliche Sphären menschlichen Seins abgedeckt.

(Hervorhebungen von mir. Inwieweit dieser Kalendereintrag Spekulation ist, habe ich nicht recherchiert.)

Comment: Gekonntes Täuschungsmanöver - aber bei genauer Betrachtung verrät das "am Arsch vorbeigehen" nicht, wieso etwas in den Fluch kommt. Sogar im Gegenteil: Ginge es uns am Allerwertesten vorbei, so würden wir uns ja nicht mit Fluchen verausgaben. :)

Comment: @user: Ja, Du hast recht. Der 1. Absatz ist nicht sonderlich informativ und soll wohl vor allem lustig formuliert sein ...

Comment: Nicht sehr überzeugend, und der explizit nachgefragte *Wolkenbruch* wird nicht mal erwähnt.

Comment: Ah, but it could be that  "Zwirn" stands for sex, like "naaien" (nähen, to sew) in Dutch.

Comment: FWIW, didn't Heinz Erhardt make that "Himmel, Gesäß und Nähgarn"? Still recognizable but not as vulgar? <g>

Answer (score 4):

**A) Ein bisschen Statistik**

Auch keine Antwort auf die Frage nach der Herkunft, aber immerhin trotzdem schon mal interessant für die Entwicklung einer solchen Antwort: Verlaufskurve von DWDS für das Auftreten der drei Wörter "Himmel, Arsch, Zwirn" zusammen (Zahlen: Vorkommen pro Million Einheiten):

[image: DWDS-Kurve Himmel Arsch Zwirn]

Demnach ist es (im verwendeten Textkorpus) erst ab 1900 nachgewiesen.

In diesem Zusammenhang fällt auf, dass z.B. anders als das Wort *Himmel*, das - wie man sich denken kann - in älterer Literatur sehr oft vorkommt, das Wort *Arsch* ebenfalls erst ab ca. 1900 häufiger in gedruckten Werken (bwz. denen, auf die sich DWDS stützt) zu finden ist:

[image: DWDS Arsch]

Hier noch die Kurve für *Himmel*:

[image: DWDS Himmel]

**B) Ansätze für eine solidere Erklärung**

Um eine solidere Erklärung für die Herkunft des Ausdrucks zu finden, würde ich folgendene Wege vorschlagen:

1) Gibt es Ausdrücke auf Latein oder auf Hebräisch, die in irgend einer Form klanglich *Himmel, Arsch und Zwirn" nahekommen und die ein dieser Sprachen nicht so mächtiger Volksfluchender mit *Himmel, Arsch und Zwirn* wiederzugeben geneigt sein könnte? Kontaktorte mit dem Mutterausdruck wären naheliegenderweise z.B. die Kirche und der örtliche Viehmarktplatz.

2) Meine ländliche, katholische, süddeutsche Verwandschaft pflegte vor Jahren bei heftigen Ärgeranfällen unausweichlich auf Griechisch zu fluchen: **Hercules!** (also wie der altgriechische mythische Halbgott). Dies war jedoch kein Ausweis klassischer Sprach- und Kulturkenntnis, vielmehr das Ergebnis der (selbstironischen) Kaschierung des eigentlichen Fluchs (**Herrgottsack!**, dies wiederum von **Herrgott Sakrament!**) durch etwas Unverfänglicheres. Also etwa:

> Bauer [fängt an zu fluchen]: **Herr...** [... und besinnt sich, leiser:] **...cules**.

Ich hielte es für einen Versuch wert, *Himmel, Arsch und Zwirn* in diesem Lichte zu untersuchen.

Comment: Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass davor einfach nur das Papier zu teuer war, um es für so einen Spruch zu verschwenden...

Comment: @tofro  Anders formuliert: Der Umstand, dass es nicht gedruckt wurde, heißt nicht, dass es nicht gesagt wurde. Das ist schon klar. Aber nach dem die andernorts publizierten Erklärungsversuche so hilflose Do-it-yourself-Etymologie waren, denke ich, ein bisschen Druckwortstatistik kann nicht schaden.

Comment: Im Jeckes/Ivrit-Lexikon-der-BenJehuda-Str muss den Hebräern dieser aus Deutschlandimportierte, und wohl noch so auf deutsch gängige, Fluch erklärt werden. Scheint keine sehr enge Verbindung zum Hebräischen z uhaben.

Comment: @LangLangC  Interessanter Hinweis. - Was sagt deine Quelle zu dem berühmten "Es zieht wie Hechtsuppe"? Das müsste vermutlich auch erklärt werden (wenn denn die gängige Erklärung aus dem hebräischen Wort für Sturm überhaupt stimmt), weil es so verballhornt ist...?

Comment: Prima Antwort. Gute Idee, überhaupt mal die Wort- und Wortgruppen-Häufigkeit nachzusehen. Es handelt sich also tatsächlich um einen "modernen", ironisch gefärbten Ausruf.  Minimale Anmerkung: *Hercules* ist nicht der griechische Name (der ist *Herakles)*, sondern der lateinische.

Answer (score 0):

Mich wundert regelmäßig, bei wie vielen Redensarten geradezu verkrampft versucht wird, schwer erklärbare Sprüche, Sprichwörter oder bloße Blabla-Floskeln wissenschaftlich, historisch, linguistisch oder sonstwie tiefenpsychologisch zu erklären. Die Art und Form dieser Wendung deutet dem sprachlich Versierten eher aufs 19./20. Jh. hin. Mein Großvater und Vater (*1895 + 1915) hatten den Spruch vom Barras mitgebracht, wo er zum Zwecke sinnlosen, aber dadurch eindrucksvollen Fluchens aus dem Nichts entstand und  zunehmende Verbreitung fand. Er klang einfach nur toll, und man konnte ihn sich deshalb gut merken.

Answer (score 0):

Zwirn ist in diesem Fall ein Deckname für den Teufel, den man bekanntlich nicht bei seinem wahren Namen nennen darf, um ihn nicht aufmerksam zu machen und anzulocken. Die Zahl der teuflischen Decknamen ist enorm und oft handelt es sich um alltägliche oder unverfängliche Gegenstände,manchmal humorvoll verbrämt, oder in vermeintlich harmlos-kindlicher Gestalt. Zum Beispiel wird oft "Beim Kuckuck" oder "Zum Kuckuck" geflucht, wobei der Vogel wie der Faden eine sexuelle Komponente haben, die den Decknamen durchaus das Potenzial eines Kraftausdrucks verleihen. Bei Zwirn liegt die Verbindung zum Teufel (aus griechisch diabolos, dem "Doppelzüngigen", dem "Zweifel Sähenden") in der Zwiefältigkeit des aus zwei Fäden bestehenden Garns. Die wahre Dreifaltigkeit, die hinter dem Fluch steckt, wird allerdings erst deutlich, wenn man die Varianten vergleicht: Die vier geläufigsten dreigliedrigen Fluchformeln auf "Himmel", die mir bekannt sind, lauten: "Himmel, Herrgott, Sakrament!", "Himmel, Arsch und Zwirn!", "Himmel, Arsch und Wolkenbruch!", sowie "Himmel, Arsch und Schornsteinfeger!". Dahinter verbirgt sich die aus der Planetenwoche (Dienstag, Mittwoch=Godestag, Donnerstag), frühmittelalterlichen Abschwörformeln und Taufgelöbnissen sowie der nordischen Edda bekannte heidnische Götter-Trias Ziu (Tyr), Gode/Wotan (Odin), Donner/Donar (Thor). Himmel ist schlicht die deutsche Übersetzung des protogermanischen Tiwaz, dem Ausgangswort von Ziu/Tyr. Ziu ist "der Himmel". Gode ist in "Herrgott" noch gut zu erkennen (Herr Gode), auch wenn die Formel den irreführenden Eindruck erweckt, es sei der christliche Gott angesprochen (was allerdings den Kraftwortcharakter durch die blasphemische Komponente steigert). Später wird der Göttervater als oberster der Dämonen mit dem verächtlichsten und schimpflichsten Ausdruck belegt, nämlich "Arsch", um den Bösen zu schmähen und seine Macht zu beschränken. Das führt noch auf Zeiten, wo Gode als höchster Abgott mit dem Teufel selbst identifiziert wurde. Später ging diese Identifizierung auf Donner/Donar über, weil das Volk an ihm am zähesten festhielt (wegen seiner Epiphanie im Unwetter). Wir erkennen den Teufel im schwarzen, rußigen Mann des "Schornsteinfegers" und wir erkennen den Wetter- und Gewittergott im "Wolkenbruch". Und "Sakrament"? Das ist eigentlich ein Stoßgebet im Augenblick höchster Not und Lebensangst und entfährt dem Menschen unwillkürlich, wenn ein greller Blitzstrahl mit dem ohrenbetäubenden Donnerschlag unmittelbar über seinem Kopf zusammenfällt (Bitte um das Sterbesakrament in der Todesstunde). Angerufen wird Christus als Zuflucht, wenn der Teufel/Donar seine Macht unverstellt zeigt.

Comment: "Bei Zwirn liegt die Verbindung zum Teufel (aus griechisch diabolos, dem "Doppelzüngigen", dem "Zweifel Sähenden") in der Zwiefältigkeit des aus zwei Fäden bestehenden Garns" Ja ja, und Zwispalt kommt daher, dass man beim Zwiebelschneiden immer weinen muss; Zwiebel und Deibel sind ja sowieso das gleiche?!? Im Ansatz zwar richtig nur leider schlecht begründet und dafür zu lang.

Answer (score -4):

Klingt ein wenig wie im Unterricht improvisiert aber schlüssig:

> Das kommt aus der Schneiderei. Bevor die Nähmaschine erfunden war,
>   nähte der Schneider im Schneidersitz mit Nadel und Faden vor sich hin.
>   Durch diese unbequeme Haltung tat ihm natürlich der Hintern weh. Das
>   Garn (Zwirn) war damals auch nicht sehr haltbar und riß deshalb
>   häufig. Der Schneider war sauer und wenn das Garn riß fluchte er:
>   "Himmelherrgott nochmal, mir tut der Arsch weh und der Zwirn ist auch
>   schon wieder gerissen!" Weil das sehr häufig passierte, verkürzte sich
>   der Fluch auf "Himmel, Arsch und Zwirn!"

Comment: Deine Antwort wäre besser, wenn Du sie belegen könntest, wie in der akzeptierten Antwort. So klingt das alles recht spekulativ, und das soll hier ja kein Ratespiel sein.

Comment: Ich würde sagen, arg konstruiert.

Comment: *»Klingt ein wenig wie im Unterricht improvisiert«*: Stimmt genau. *»... aber schlüssig«*: Nein. Das ist keineswegs schlüssig. Ein Vier-Worte-Fluch entstehen nicht dadurch, dass man aus einem Satz mit 15 Wörtern auf einem Schlag 11 Wörter weglässt und gleichzeitig eines der verbleibenden durch ein anderes ersetzt. So funktioniert Sprache nicht. Außerdem geht auch diese Antwort nicht auf den *Wolkenbruch* ein, nach dem ja auch gefragt wurde.

Comment: @Hubert: welches wurde durch ein anderes ersetzt? Meinst du Himmelherrgott durch Himmel? Finde die Erklärung ehrlich gesagt gar nicht so unschlüssig.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Angeblicher Ursprung: *»Himmelherrgott nochmal, mir tut der Arsch weh und der Zwirn ist auch schon wieder gerissen«.* Daraus muss man diese 11 Wörter weglassen: *nochmal, mir, tut, der, weh, der, ist, auch, schon, wieder* und *gerissen*. Dann bleiben: *Himmelherrgott, Arsch, und* und *Zwirn.* Geändert werden muss dann auch noch *Himmelherrgott → Himmel*. Das sind ziemlich viele Veränderungen, die laut Julius alle zugleich hätten stattfinden müssen. Das halte ich, um *user unknown* zu zitieren, für *»arg konstruiert«*.

Comment: @Hubert: Ich nicht. Dass man viel weglassen muss liegt nur daran, dass es sehr umständlich gesagt wurde. Und dass aus Himmelherrgott nur Himmel übrigbleibt kommt mir ganz natürlich vor. Dass das so kondensiert wurde ist m.E. nicht unglaubwürdig. Ich glaube zwar nicht, dass das die Herkunft ist, aber es hätte so sein können.